# Do we really need a mutex in this case?

Tags: concurrency, synchronization, mutual-exclusion

Wikipedia's [solution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem#Using_semaphores) for ***multi*** Producer-Consumer problem uses both mutexes and semaphores.

```
mutex buffer_mutex; 
semaphore fillCount = 0;
semaphore emptyCount = BUFFER_SIZE;

procedure producer() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        item = produceItem();
        down(emptyCount);
        down(buffer_mutex);
        putItemIntoBuffer(item);
        up(buffer_mutex);
        up(fillCount);
    }
}

procedure consumer() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        down(fillCount);
        down(buffer_mutex);
        item = removeItemFromBuffer();
        up(buffer_mutex);
        up(emptyCount);
        consumeItem(item);
    }
}
```

The reason given for using a mutex is to enforce mutual exclusion when multiple producers and consumers are in the critical section. My question is, since the goal is to have a single thread in the critical section anyway, why not just use a binary semaphore, which ensures this? That is, can we do away with the mutexes if we use binary semaphores in that example?

Can we have something like this instead?

```
semaphore empty = 1
semaphore full = 0
procedure producer() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        down(empty);
        putItemIntoBuffer(item);
        up(full);
    }
}

procedure consumer() 
{
    while (true) 
    {
        down(full);
        item = removeItemFromBuffer();
        up(empty);
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes. Simply because a binary semaphore is a possible implementation of an advisory lock/mutex. The discussion preceding the code in the wikipedia could be improved.

Comment: Hi @Kai, Can you kindly elaborate? Can you, for e.g, describe a scenario in which not using a mutex could be a problematic, like in the edited version above?

Comment: Sorry, I interpreted your original question before the edit differently. The edited version doesn't make sense. It does not describe at all how a produced item is communicated to the consumer.

Comment: Hi, I edited it to clarify. We assume that there is shared queue between consumer and producer. When the producer gets into the c.s., it puts something into the buffer. When the consumer gets into the c.s., it gets an item.

Comment: This is wrong. You haven't described how the producer (consumer) reacts when the queue is full (empty).

Comment: That is not the point. Assume it's an unbounded buffer if it helps. The question, is if multiple producers and consumers were trying to put and get items in the queue, would the 2nd version help.

Comment: Your proposal would not benefit at all from having a more-than-one-place buffer. So making it unbounded is pointless. What you are describing is akin to a simple critical section solution but with two sets of processes that are forced to take alternating turns: odd turns must be taken by producers whereas even turns must be taken by consumer. That's much more restrictive than the wikipedia suggestion which enforces the number of items placed in the buffer minus the number of items taken out must always be between 0 and BUFFER_SIZE. (That difference never exceeds 1 in your suggestion.)